# How to bind all methods of a class to the 'this' variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, this

I have a class in JavaScript (MyClass) which exposes two public functions (funA and funB) as shown:

```
var MyClass = function(){
  this.funA = function(){
    console.log("function A");
    this.funB();
  };
  this.funB = function(){
    console.log("function B");
  };
};

var myObj = new MyClass();
```

Note how funA calls funB using 'this' keyword.

The following works:

```
myObj.funA();
```

But this does not:

```
var anonymousFun = function(fn){
  fn();
}
anonymousFun(myObj.funA);
```

The reason is when funA calls funB using 'this', the 'this' is set to global context (instead of MyClass) and funB does not exist at global level.
The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.funB is not a function
```

The simplest solution that I tried to avoid the issue is to use a variable 'that' inside MyClass and initialize it to 'this'. Then, use that.funB instead of this.funB inside funA:

```
var MyClass = function(){
  var that = this;
  this.funA = function(){
    console.log("function A");
    that.funB();
  };
  this.funB = function(){
    console.log("function B");
  };
};
```

Is this a correct approach?
Are there any better solutions available?

Comment: This is *very* much a matter of opinion and this off-topic. (He said, deleting the paragraph of opinion he was about to express).

Answer (score 5):

If you're compiling your JS with Babel you can use class property initilizer syntax to create functions that are bound to `this`:

```
class MyClass {
  funA = () => {
    console.log('function A')
    this.funB()
  }

  funB = () => {
    console.log('function B')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Function.bind` method to attach an object which is to be used as "this" when the function is called.

`anonymousFun(myObj.funA.bind(myObj));`

Answer (score 1):

It's more like an opinion based question. Though, this might help you in your development. You can use bind or call. Here's an example with call:

```js
var MyClass = function(){
  this.funA = function(){
    console.log("function A");
    this.funB();
  };
  this.funB = function(){
    console.log("function B");
  };
};

var myObj = new MyClass();

var anonymousFun = function(fn){
  fn.call(myObj)
}
anonymousFun(myObj.funA)
```

A little better:

```
var anonymousFun = function(context, fn){
  fn.call(context)
}
anonymousFun(myObj, myObj.funA)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the functions using identifiers accessible within the scope of the constructor, then add them to the Object at the end. `this` may change depending on context, but a closure is a closure and references to variables accessible to the function will not change.

```js
var MyClass = function(){
  function funA(){ // no `this`
    console.log("function A");
    funB(); // no `this`
  };
  function funB(){ // no `this`
    console.log("function B");
  };

  Object.assign(this, { funA, funB });
};

var instance = new MyClass();

instance.funA();
instance.funB();

var lonely = instance.funA;

lonely(); // no longer attached to an object, but can still access funB();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use arrow functions instead. The reason that this becomes a window object is due to a different closure. If you use arrow functions when defining the functions, you with retain the same closure through out the class.

```
var MyClass = function(){
  this.funA = ()=>{
    console.log("function A");
    this.funB();
  };
  this.funB =()=>{
    console.log("function B");
  };
};
```

This code works as expected